# PHP connection to remote mysql with ssl works via command but not in browser

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, browser

I want to connect to a **remote** (AWS) **mysql** server using **ssl** in **PHP**.

My script works when I execute it via command line, but doesn't when I call it from the browser.

```
$con=mysqli_init();
mysqli_ssl_set($con,NULL,NULL,"path/to/cacert.pem",NULL,NULL);
$link = mysqli_real_connect($con, "host", "username", "password");
```

I am using *php7/Apache/CentOs*. I tried changing the *ownership* and *permissions* of the *CA file*, and noticed that it requires read permission the be executed on console. But in browser even if I give *full permission* to everybody (chmod 777) it still doesn't work.

The error i get is:
**Warning: failed loading cafile stream.**
When I check existence of file it returns true, but when I check is_readible, then also error.

Can somebody help?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So as I figured there was (is) something wrong with readability and maybe permissions. I could narrow down the problem to the certificate file being existent but not readable. I moved it to my server with filezilla via ftp.

I could solve my problem by creating a new .pem file and simply copying the content of my original file into it. This one is readable now and works in browser, but I can't figure out why as they both have the same *chmod xxx* permissions and *chown* ownership.

**Detailed description**(for users with similar problem using *AWS MYSQL*)**:**

1. open *rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem* file(download link: https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem) in text editor.
2. Copy content.
3. On your server, where php script should run create new file and paste text into it.(it might require some additional editing, begin/end tags in separate line and new lines end at the same place as in original text)